# How to access TPanel child form controls?

Tags: forms, delphi, parent, delphi-xe3, tpanel

I have a main form with `TPanel`. I have also a `Form2` with a `TButton` which I show in `TPanel` as a child. I mean `TPanel` of main form is parent of `Form2`. I use these steps to create the form2 in `MainForm` `OnCreate` method

```
MainFormOnCreate()

Form2 := TForm2.create(nil)
Form2.Parent := Panel1;
Form2.show;
```

But the problem is that when I access the button on `Form2` it does nothing. For example, when I want to disable the button on `Form2` I use this method

A button2 on main form with on click event

```
btn2OnClick();
Form2.btn.enabled := false;
```

But it does nothing. Some friends says it's because of child to `TPanel` it will get no message.

So give me a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't posted any real code. (`MainFormOnCreate()` and `btn2OnClick()` aren't actual code that will compile, there's no `begin` or `end`, and you haven't shown where `Form2` is defined at all.) Please [edit] your question and post some actual code and variable declarations so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is, that you create 2 instances of `TForm2`.

Your `.dpr` file look like this

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm( TForm1, Form1 );
  Application.CreateForm( TForm2, Form2 );
  Application.Run;
end.
```

After you create an instance of `TForm2` in `TForm1.OnCreate` and save this instance into global variable `Form2`, another instance of `TForm2` is created and stored into `Form2`.

In the `TForm1.btn5.OnClick` event you address the second created, non visible `TForm2`.

---

### Solution

- go to *Project / Options* -> *Formula* and remove `TForm2` from *AutoCreate List*
- store the instance of `TForm2` created inside of `TForm1` in a private class field of `TForm1`

Your code should look like this

*.dpr* file:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm( TForm1, Form1 );
  Application.Run;
end.
```

*Unit1.pas*

```
TForm1 = class( TForm )
...
procedure FormCreate( Sender : TObject );
procedure btn2Click( Sender : TObject );
private
  FForm2 : TForm2;
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate( Sender : TObject );
begin
  FForm2 := TForm2.Create( Self );
  FForm2.Parent := Panel1;
  FForm2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click( Sender : TObject );
begin
  FForm2.btn.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: *"To avoid memory leaks .."* - A parent control (necessarily a wincontrol) assumes responsibility of destroying its controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    lForm: TForm;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(lForm) then
    TForm2(lForm).Button1.Enabled:= False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lForm := TForm2.Create(self);
  lForm.Parent := Panel1;
  lForm.Align:= alClient;
  lForm.show;
end;
```